# Inner Loop Issue

Tags: python

I have main function for get items from data object and send them to checked object

```
async def main():
   for item in data:
    
    is_Checked = False
    for checkedItem in checked['items']:
        if(checkedItem['id'] == item['id']):
            is_Checked= True
    if is_Checked:
        continue

    await sendItem(item)
```

I call this function like that.Because I want keep running main function

```
run = 1
while run ==1:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        await main()
        time.sleep(.1)
```

But when it checked all items he turn over and sending same items again.
I want wait until new item add to data

Comment: This code snippet is missing some things. The objects `data` and `checked` are used but never defined in `main()`. What are they and where do they come from? What is `sendItem()` doing? Where are you "checking" that you are not seeing what you want? What do you want to see when you do check there?

Comment: Skip the (explicit) inner loop altogether and use `is_checked = any(x['id'] == item['id'] for x in checked['items'])`.